# Помогите с адаптивным гридом

Tags: css, grid

Вроде простая задача и скорее всего решение какое то очевидное, но я что-то запутался.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я конечно могу что то закостылять индивидуально для данного случая, но хотелось бы какое то универсальное решение применимое для многих случаев.

Comment: С чем именно проблема? используйте [flex](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex) или [grid](https://caniuse.com/#search=grid) и [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Все эти три блока внутри грида, если я задаю ширину колонкам внутри грида и адаптирую их в первом случае 4/12 т.е. по 33.3% на мобильной версии по 100% 12/12 то как быть с промежуточной адаптацией на планшет 50%, 50% и 100%? С использованием flex?

Comment: Думаю эта [статья](https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/common-responsive-layouts-with-css-grid-and-some-without-245a862f48df) закроет все твои вопросы